# Is there any equivalent proverb for "Slow and steady wins the race"?

Tags: grammar, phrase-request, proverb

From the famous story of the race between **`Hare`** and **`Tortoise`** we learn many things one of which is the moral.

> Slow and steady wins the race

Are there any equivalent proverbs/sayings to deal with situations like this in Korean language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one korean proverb that has the similar meaning:

> [잰 놈 뜬 놈만
>   못하다.](http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=32441700&offset=IDIOM13137#IDIOM13137)

'재다' is an adjective which means 'quick' or 'fast' and '뜨다' as an adjective (not broadly used in Korean) means 'slow'. It literally translates to:

> A quick guy is worse than a slow guy.

[네이버 국어사전]

Answer (score 1):

I just come up with one traditional fairy tale "토끼와 거북이"(The hare and the turtle) which exactly describes the proverb you mentioned.

So Korean use that phrase like this : "Like the story of 토끼와 거북이, he finally wins the first prize in the competition."

Comment: Welcome to Korean SE. The OP is asking for a proverb. Can you write the full sentence in Korean? Also, please try to fix typos when you post an answer.

Comment: I can't bring up any proverb now that means exactly the same thing the OP means. Do you want me to delete my answer?

Comment: No need to delete an answer. What I think @Rathony meant is to explain a little more or full sentence in Korean. Any effort is good as you did here. Thanks for your effort again.